# Ensuring that jquery DataTable can sort based on invoking by AJAX a Server-Side C# method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, datatables, server-side

Here is the information about my development environment:

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013

.NET Framework 4.0

jquery.min.js 1.11.3

jquery-ui.min.js  1.11.2

jQuery DataTables 1.10.7

Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1

We implemented the tables on our website using jQuery DataTables that involved Server-Side Pagination.  In other words, the application will only retrieve data from the database as the user clicks on the Page numbers or Page arrow keys at the bottom of the table.

```
  $('#GameMatchRecordsLogTable').DataTable({
                        "aoColumns": [
                                        { "sTitle": "MatchId" },
                                         { "sTitle": "OrganizerUserID" }, {
 "sTitle": "Team1", "bSortable":
 true }, { "sTitle": "Team2",
 "bSortable": true },
                                         { "sTitle": "DATE", "sType":
"datetime-us-asc", "bSortable":
true },
                                            ],
                             "bAutoWidth":false,
                            "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData,
    iDisplayIndex) {
                                $(nRow).addClass("gradeX");
                            },
                            "iDisplayLength": 10,
                              "sDom": '<"clear">frtip',
                             "bProcessing": true,
                              "bServerSide": true,
                            "bLengthChange": false,
                            "bPaginate": true,
                            "bDestroy": true,
                            "bSort": true,
                            "aaSorting": [],
                        "bInfo": true,
                        "bFilter": false,
                        "sAjaxSource":
'GameMatchesList.aspx/SearchBasedOnMultipleCriteriaForGameMatches',
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "bDeferRender": true,

                        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                              aoData.push(
                                         { "name": "sortColumnArg",
"value": sortColumnArg }
                                       , { "name": "isDescendingArg",
 "value": isDescendingArg }
                                       , { "name": "startDateArg",
"value": startDateArg }
                                       , { "name": "endDateArg", "value":
endDateArg }
                                       , { "name": "OwnersNameArg",
 "value": OwnersNameArg }
                                        , { "name":
"searchDrpDutyCycleArg", "value":
searchDrpDutyCycleArg }
                                       , { "name":
"searchDrpSignedStateArg", "value":
searchDrpSignedStateArg }
                            );
                       },
                        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData,
fnCallback) {
                        $.ajax({

                            "dataType": 'json',
                            "contentType": "application/json;
charset=utf-8",
                                "type": "GET",
                                "url": sSource,
                                "data": aoData,
                                "success":
                                         function (msg) {
                                             var obj =
 jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                                            fnCallback(obj);

                                        },

                                beforeSend: function () {
                                    $('.loader').show()
                                },
                                 complete: function () {
                                    $('.loader').hide()

                                }
                             });
                       }
                    });
```

The back-end C# code will resemble something like the following:

```
       [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle =
WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method = "GET")]
         public static string
SearchBasedOnMultipleCriteriaForGameMatches()
        {

           return null;
         }
```

We also need Server-side based sorting for the title headers of the jquery DataTable.

To elaborate, we want user to be able to click on the title Header of the DATE column which would in turn invoke AJAX method which in turn invokes a Server-side C# to get all the Data based on a particular order of the Date , therefore, if user toggles then it would go back and forth between descending and ascending of Date ).

Could someone please explain how I could implementing the aforementioned requirement?

Comment: It's made here in PHP but I'm sure you can adapt it to c#. It is a pure server side issue http://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/

Comment: I quickly reviewed the webpage with the example.  Could you please mention where on the aforementioned webpage it gives details about sorting by clicking on column header arrow?

Comment: You don't have to manage this. the datatable plugin will do. Just have to write the server side part afaik.